# TortoiseSVN import menu item missing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Successfully created a new repository on windows 10 with path `file:///C:/MyProj_Repo`. Then created a working folder `C:\MyForkingFolder`. But when I click on the working folder to add ir to repository and try to select `TortoiseSVN-->Import` the import submenu is missing as shown below. Why is that and how to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: I get Import as an option right clicking on `C:` when my svn projects are `C:\project1` `C:\project2` etc.  This is not an answer because I don't feel safe talking about why that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn import` helps you add unversioned items to the repository. It should be normally used for items that are not in working copy. Since you already have a working copy, use `svn add` and then `svn commit`. The screenshot has both these commands.